# Why dativ when we do not know the position

Tags: sentence-structure, grammaticality

In the following sentences why does one use the dative ("meiner") instead of the accusative ("meine")?

> meiner Meinung dazu..
>
> meiner Meinung nach...

And can you make a sentence with both of the phrases?
The reference is the "Menschen" book by Huber, B1 level.
For example:

> Meiner Meinung nach ist die Wohnung sehr klein.

Comment: _meiner Meinung dazu_ is wrong, it must be _meine Meinung dazu_. Where did you get that from? Clarify that in your question please. Either add a link to the source, or put more context there, neither of these sentences is complete.

Comment: *... meiner Meinung dazu ...* could be part of a valid sentence, but to decide this one has to see the entire sentence. It is impossible to say much about it from the fragment alone.

Comment: Because *nach* as either a preposition or a postposition takes dative case.

Comment: Thnx guys. I edited my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you shouldn't post fragments, but whole sentences. We are talking about grammar here, and grammar is the science of joining words together to build *sentences,* not *fragments.* So, I try it with these sentences:

> 1. **Meiner Meinung** dazu ist, dass die Wohnung sehr klein ist.
> 2. **Meiner Meinung** nach ist die Wohnung sehr klein.

---

### 1

Now note, that sentence 1 is wrong! The bold marked part of speech is the subject, and the subject always must be in nominative case. So, your assumption about dative case is just wrong for sentence 1.

This is correct:

> **Meine Meinung** dazu ist, dass die Wohnung sehr klein ist.
> **My opinion** on this is that the apartment is very small.

The word *"dazu"* is a pronominal adverb. It consists of the adverb *"da"* and the preposition *"zu".* In this sentence it works like a prepositional object and it can be replaced by one:

> Meine Meinung *zu dieser Sache* ist, dass die Wohnung sehr klein ist.
> My opinion *on this matter* is that the apartment is very small.

So, in sentence 1 the word *"dazu"* is a distinct part of speech, that does not directly belong to *"meine Meinung"* and even can be omitted completely:

> Meine Meinung ist, dass die Wohnung sehr klein ist.
> My opinion is that the apartment is very small.

---

### 2

The sentence 2 is correct, but note, that the word **nach** is an adposition, that most often appears as a preposition, but here is a postposition. And, even more important, it is not a distinct part of speech. It is part of

> meiner Meinung nach
> according to my opinion (in my opinion)

which is a postpositional object. Postpositional objects work exactly like prepositional objects, the only difference is the place on the adposition inside this object. You also can convert the postpositional object into a prepositional object:

> **Nach meiner Meinung** ist die Wohnung sehr klein.
> **According to my opinion (in my opinion)** the apartment is very small.

But the phrase *"meiner Meinung nach"* is much more common than *"nach meiner Meinung",* but both of them are correct and they mean the same.

The point is, that each adposition wants to have the rest of the adpositional object to be in some specific grammatical case. And *"nach"* wants dative case. And this is the reason why *"meiner Meinung"* in *"meiner Meinung nach"* has to be in dative case.

Comment: In my opinion, *meiner Meinung nach* is not an object because it can be used with almost any verb. It is rather an epistemic adverbial.

Comment: Thank you very much hubert. You answer was realllllly complete. Can you make me an example of other positions that we can transfer postpositional objects to prepositional ?

Comment: @omidrezanouri: Comments are not meant to ask new questions. Ask your question [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).